# Can't watch MP4 videos in Fedora 26

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, fedora, mp4

I'm having a problem trying to watch MP4 videos in Fedora 26.

After I installed the gstreamer packages from rpmfusion, I get the following error:

```
Error: nothing provides libvpx.so.4()(64bit) needed by ffmpeg-libs-3.1.4-2.fc26.x86_64
```

I tried to install libvpx but it's already installed as package libvpx-1.5.0-4.fc24.x86_64 that is being referenced by other programs.

Is it possible to upgrade that package without uninstalling the programs that reference it?

Comment: Fedora 26 is not released and therefore there are not build third party codecs and similar. Use some of the released versions (and supported) to get full features.

Comment: I realize now that it should be the problem since you now comment this. I'm going to search for a media player that has built in the codecs needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Which OP system do you use, Linux ... bits ?
**Probably you have 32 bits and program is on 64 bits.**

> libvpx.so.4()(64bit) needed by ffmpeg-libs-3.1.4-2.fc26.x86_64

Install driver for mp4 from player codecs from media player (i know that only windows, but probably also Linux there).
I have myself Linux lime and it worked, try another driver for programm and don`t forget your OS compatibility -> 64 runs 32 and 64; 32 runs 32 and 16 (Windows 95 domain).

**Another possibility can be that it was not installed correctly, or the OS system was too "pimped" for the program to run correctly.
Try reinstalling program --> restart your PC.**
Your sincere,
*George Andrew-member since today 10/16/2016*